# Windows Azure Websites - Get Instance Identifier

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

What's a possible way to determine on an Azure website with multiple instances what instance is responding (some ID or other piece of unique info)?

Comment: No, I have decided not proceed this route as it seem to be problematic.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The following environment setting will have the instance id the current request is running on: **WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID**.

You'll also receive this id as a cookie in the response named: **ARRAffinity**.

You can also use this information to get back to that specific instance, see: http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/03/access-specific-instance/ for more information about it.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Azure provides many environment variables for Azure Web Apps (formerly known as Website), including the following:

- `WEBSITE_SITE_NAME`  - the name of the site.
- `WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID`- the id representing the VM that the site is running on.
- etc

  See [Azure Runtime Environment](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#website-environment-variables) by David Ebbo for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Server.MachineName to get the name of the server.

Answer (score 1):

2022-06-06

### Configuration of Web App

[image]

### How to find Instance

1.This is an instance ID.

[image]

2.Go to see the environment

[image]

3.Find which variable is `pl1sdlwk0001WS`, and `COMPUTERNAME` is that you want.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set up `InstanceInputEndpoint` in configuration. This will allocate ports from the given port range for each instance, then you can visit a instance through the port.

For more information about `InstanceInputEndpoint`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg557553.aspx

Comment: this is for Azure Web Roles, not Azure Websites (now named Azure Web Apps)

Answer (score 0):

New answer to an old question. I found this worked with .net 6, Azure Function v4, and worked well with hosting on a multi-instance App Server Plan. The value it returns matches the "Server Name" as listed in Application Insights.

```
        var instanceName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID");
```

I then injected this into my logging

```
            Logger log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .Enrich.WithProperty("InstanceName", instanceName)
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .WriteTo.AzureBlobStorage(
```

and accessed it by setting it up in my Serilogger output template:

```
        "Logging:OutputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}][{InstanceName}][{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
```

Note: this resolves to *null* when debugging locally.

Answer (score -2):

You can use RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id

Comment: This doesn't work on Azure Websites, perhaps because this is for WebRoles?

Answer (score -3):

Request.ServerName I believe. Just like vanilla IIS

Comment: That doesn't work. When you have multiple instances (dedicated mode) the server name returned is the same for all instances ([website-name].azurewebsites.net)

Comment: `Request.ServerName` isn't a valid property. I assume you meant `Request.ServerVariables[“SERVER_NAME”]`?